# Trane xv90 blower won't come on regardless of what the thermostat is set at

Tags: hvac, blower

I have a trane xv90 and the blower won't come on.  I'm getting about 20 green flashing lights and then 1 red which kinda overlaps the 21st green.  What does it mean?  I had turned on my trane air conditioner from thermostat and air conditioner fuse, but forgot to turn on the circuit breaker for the air conditioner...so at first its blades weren't turning and it made a weird sound, however, I discovered this and then turned the circuit breaker on.  Air conditioner is working fine but furnace blower isn't coming on...tried turning everything off and restarting but it still didn't fix it....any suggestions?

Comment: Your furnace/blower should have both a dedicated circuit breaker and possibly an on/off switch of its own. The switch would look like a normal light switch and should be near the furnace/blower assembly. Make sure these are both in the "on" position. +1 do give you some points...it might help to edit and include a picture of these lights if you can.

Comment: Same weird error code here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: no resolution so far,,,still hoping someone else has insight to the problem. Tried again and this time it seems there were 40 blinking green and then 1 red...anyone have any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!